# i get wrong results from mysql join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables, that i want to join, one is rooms and another is reservations.

Basically I want to search for rooms which are not reserved (not in reservation table) and to get the details of those rooms (which are not in reservation table) from room table.

Here are my tables structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `room` (
   `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomtypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `roomName_en` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `roomDescription` text,
   `roomDescription_en` text,
   `roomSorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomVisible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`roomID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
    `reservationID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `customerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `reservationCreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
    `reservationCreatedFromIp` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET greek NOT NULL,
    `reservationNumberOfAdults` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `reservationNumberOfChildrens` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `reservationArrivalDate` date NOT NULL,
    `reservationDepartureDate` date NOT NULL,
    `reservationCustomerComment` text CHARACTER SET greek,
    PRIMARY KEY (`reservationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE `reservationroom` (
  `reservationroomID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reservationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hotelID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `roomID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservationroomID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the query that I have right now, which gives me wrong results:

```
SELECT * FROM room r 
LEFT JOIN reservation re
ON r.hotelID = re.hotelID
WHERE re.hotelID = 13
AND NOT 
(re.reservationArrivalDate >= '2014-07-07' AND  re.reservationDepartureDate <= '2014-07-13')
```

I also have created a fiddle, with the data from both tables included:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb9ea/1

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Regards, John

Comment: `reservation` has no `roomID` foreign key. How do you mark a room as reserved?

Comment: Yes. One would normally reserve a room rather than the whole hotel.

Comment: i have another table, reservationroom, because one reservation may have more than one room...should i include that table in my query as well?

Comment: Well, we can't tell which rooms are reserved without it, so seems like a good idea to me!

Comment: post has been updated now, i am now updating the fiddle

Comment: i have some problems with updating the fiddle...working on it...

Answer (score 0):

i agree that room number was missed,
but query template should looks like

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  room r 
  LEFT JOIN reservation re 
    ON r.hotelID = re.hotelID 
WHERE r.hotelID = 2 
  AND NOT (
    re.hotelID IS NOT NULL 
    AND re.reservationArrivalDate >= '2014-07-07' 
    AND re.reservationDepartureDate <= '2014-09-23'
  ) ;
```

You need change table in where statement from reservation  to room. Also you need add re.hotelID to where statement as well, because on where statement you need check that record is not null ans only after try to check dates

Comment: this queyr return 15 results, i am expecting only 5...if the hotel id is 13

Comment: you can use GROUP BY r.hotelID, r.roomID;. In this case it will return 5 records. In first variant it returns 15 records because there is connection with reservation. In this case u will get only available rooms

Answer (score 0):

Given the newly-added `reservationroom` table, consider using a `NOT EXISTS` sub-query to find rooms without reservations:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 room r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 
   *
  FROM 
   reservationroom rr
 WHERE 
   rr.reservationroomID = r.roomID
 )
```